# Type "motherfunction" of some sort

Tags: haskell

The Haskell adventure continues.

At the moment, i am trying to construct my own Fraction type in Haskell that suits my needs.
It's basically just a type Fraction{ n:: Int , d:: Int} and a lot of functions , most of them are of type x->Fraction

So what i wanna do now is making sure that fractions can only be positive, or negative in the numerator, positive in denominator, by converting any other possibilities to one of those.

```
   --e.g
      (Fraction (3 (-5))->Fraction (-3) 5
   --and
      (Fraction (-3) (-5))->Fraction 3 5
```

every time some function x->Fraction would return one of those.
I assume there must be a smarter way to do this than modifying every x->Fraction function one by one. My guess would be already at the Fraction Type definition.

I haven't been programming for that long so i might not be completely up to beat on the technical terms.

Thanks for reading, and thanks if you answer

**EDIT**

I decided to go with the Eq Instance solution, and just added that if Signum numerator*Signum denominator doesn't match , return false, to the guard. I had to make that anyways to divide num. and den. with HCD before comparing

The smart-constructor that i originally asked for, is also gonna be used in my Matrix nXn (Q) Module that I'm making on the same time :)

Great answers. Thanks.

Comment: If you're doing this to learn Haskell: great! Otherwise, you should go ahead and use [`Ratio`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Ratio.html) and in particular `Rational` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm supposing one idea would be to keep the internal representation as it is. That is, you won't care about the actual sign of your numerator and denominator until you're doing operations with your numbers.

For example if you want to compare two Fraction numbers, which would be done by deriving an instance of the Eq class (that would of course involve having a bit of knowledge about [type classes](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Classes_and_types)), you can simply check that

```
signum d1 * signum n1 == signum d2 * signum n2
```

In addition to checking the values.

Be aware that there's also other aspects to check when dealing with fractions. For example:

```
Fraction 6 2 == Fraction 3 1
```

An alternative would involve adding a separate sign field and using something like [Natural](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/moretypes.html) numbers for the numerator and denominator.

Comment: `Fraction a b == Fraction c d = a*d == b*c` is the usual way of doing it, that also takes care of the sign.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [smart constructors](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Smart_constructors) to ensure these constraints on your type and hide the data constructors by not exporting them. A smart constructor is essentially a function that guarantees constraints that can't be enforced by the type system.

Answer (score 5):

I would actually let the values like they are and just go on computing, but if you really want: Put the definition of `Fraction` in a seperate module, and don't export its constructor. Instead, export a function like `makeFraction :: Int -> Int -> Fraction`, that takes care of your "conversion".

Now, everyone outside the module will only be able to construct the fractions the way you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you are really using `Int` rather than `Integer`, then the type system (and implementation) can solve this particular problem without any tricks or hiding. The type `Word` represents positive machine integers:

```
Prelude Data.Word> [minBound,maxBound] :: [Word]
[0,18446744073709551615]
Prelude Data.Word> [minBound,maxBound] :: [Int]
[-9223372036854775808,9223372036854775807]
```

So you can write:

```
import Data.Word

data Fraction = Int :/ Word deriving Show

fi = fromIntegral

instance Eq Fraction where
  (i :/ w) == (j :/ v) = i * fi v == j * fi w

instance Num Fraction where
  fromInteger n = fromInteger n :/ 1
  (i :/ w) * (j :/ v) = (i * j) :/ (w * v)
  (i :/ w) + (j :/ v) = i * fi v + j * fi w :/ w * v 
  (i :/ w) - (j :/ v) =  (i :/ w) + (negate j :/ v)
  negate (i :/ w) = (negate i:/ w)
  abs (i :/ w) = (abs i :/ w)  
  signum (i :/ w) = (signum i :/ 1)
```

You'll get more machine-number-like behavior with strictness and unpacking:

```
 data Fraction = {-#UNPACK#-} !Int :/ {-#UNPACK#-} !Word deriving Show
```